# Strange ZPL code receive from UPS (How to decode this ZPL code?)

Tags: api, label, zebra-printers, zpl, ups

I send 'ShipRequest' using UPS API, and I know that we can receive label image as a response by UPS.

But when I request image format as 'ZPL', it is not coming as ZPL language but coming as unknown language as below:

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

The ZPL language should be like below:
^XA
^FO40, 40
^GB300,203,8^FS
...
...

So what is this language response by UPS and how can I decode this unknown language to ZPL language?

Thank you All!

Comment: This might be a good question for their tech support, if something is wrong with their API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, carrier web service return a ZPL code, encoded in base 64. Just decode it and you will get the real ZPL code generated by UPS. (try with https://www.base64decode.org/)

It look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGxMo.jpg

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot!

Comment: @SungjinKim Could you please provide Java code reference by using it I can convert response into ZPL String

Answer (score 0):

Copy & paste the above code in 'base64decode' url. You'll get the ZPL format label string.

Decode from Base64 format
https://www.base64decode.org/

Then Copy the string and paste in 'labelary' url. Redraw the image and you'll see sample label print.

http://labelary.com/viewer.html

Above mention is manual work. You can do this using API. Just decode the string in code and send the ZPL sting to following API. You'll get the label image and send it to thermal printer. First check it on postman.

http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/

Following are the sample image received after doing the following:

1. Decode the string
2. paste the zpl string on 'labelary' url.

[image]